# Callback within redux saga

Tags: javascript, redux, callback, redux-saga, antd

I'm using Ant Design's [Modal.confirm](https://ant.design/components/modal/#Modal.method()) within my saga and I'm trying to pass a callback that dispatches an action in one of the modal params.

I've tried using channels explain in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031832/how-to-yield-put-in-redux-saga-within-a-callback), but I think I've gotten the wrong idea on how to tackle this problem.

```
function* editCustomer(action) {
  try {
let postBody = { overwrite: action.payload.overwrite }
    let customerResponse = yield call(_api.execute, url, "POST", postBody);
  } catch (error) {
    if (statusCode === 409) {
     /// duplicate data, pass in overwrite
      Modal.confirm({
        title: 'Sample title',
        onOk: () => {
          editCustomerChannel.put(_customerActions.editCustomer({ 
            overwrite: true 
         }))
        }
      })      

    } else {
      yield put({ type: "CUSTOMERS__EDIT_CUSTOMER_FAILED" });
    }
  }
}

/// CustomerSagas
export default [
  takeEvery('CUSTOMERS__SET_CUSTOMER_OWNER', setCustomerOwner),
];
```

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([...CustomersSagas]);
}
```

My sample code shows the `editCustomer` saga. I'm expecting `_api.execute` to throw an error within in the try/catch block, then Modal.confirm is called with the callback to call `editCustomer` again with the `overwrite` key set to `true`. My problem is I can't dispatch `editCustomer` in the callback.

How should I tackle this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you dispatching the action in your component?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use `store.dispatch()` directly:

```
# Wherever your configured store is
import { store } from './store' 

function* editCustomer(action) {
  try {
let postBody = { overwrite: action.payload.overwrite }
    let customerResponse = yield call(_api.execute, url, "POST", postBody);
  } catch (error) {
    if (statusCode === 409) {
     /// duplicate data, pass in overwrite
      yield call([Modal, 'confirm'], {
        title: 'Sample title',
        onOk: () => {
          store.dispatch(_customerActions.editCustomer({ 
            overwrite: true 
         }))
        })
      })      

    } else {
      yield put({ type: "CUSTOMERS__EDIT_CUSTOMER_FAILED" });
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that I also replaced `Modal.confirm({...})` with `yield call([Modal, 'confirm'], ...)` which is not directly related to your problem but is generally the correct way to make function calls to external APIs/tools/etc within a saga.